# JAVA : Program Works in Terminal , But not in Visual Studio Code : Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, visual-studio-code

My JAVA Programs used to run without any errors on both the Terminal and Visual Studio Code's Terminal .

After my Mac updated  to MacOs Big Sur Version 11.0.1 , my JAVA programs show an error , even though the same code worked properly before .

[image]

[image]

There was no error before.

I checked my JDK and JRE Installations also

[image]

My Python files execute normally in the VS Code environment , so I do not think there is a problem with VS Code .

I have tried searching for an solution and have tried to clear the logs.

[image]

I would appreciate if anyone could guide me :)

Comment: your java version in vscode might be different from terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run the .java file in Terminal to check if JDK can work normally:

   ```
    javac Hey.java
    java Hey
   ```
2. If there's nothing wrong with the above command execution, turn to VS Code, uninstall **Java Extension Pack** and also delete the related folders under `User/name/.vscode/extensions`, then reinstall it again;
3. Set `java.home` and `java.configuration.runtimes` in User Settings.json.

> Reference: [Configure JDK](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-jdk).

Then run the project again to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yeah , as mentioned in the question , the program works perfectly in the terminal , but does not execute in VS Code . And Thank You :) It Works !

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the java plugin in VS Code.

Comment: I'm sorry , but , I have already downloaded the main Microsoft JAVA extension , along with other suggested extensions for JAVA . I tried re installing , but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Install Java by searching for extensions in VSCode and try to run again.It will be executed. I belive it is not installed

Comment: I'm sorry , but , I have already downloaded the main Microsoft JAVA extension , along with other suggested extensions for JAVA . I tried re installing , but it still shows the same error

Comment: @Vishnu Joshi I think i said to install on VSCode not on Mac

Comment: Yeah , thats what I meant . I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I had installed all the VS Code Extensions for JAVA on my Mac.

Comment: Tried to run ? It will show Java Debugger Console On terminal when executed

Comment: I would request you to please re - read  the question . It opened the  JAVA debugger console and showed 7 different errors and didn't let the program run

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed it early worked. So then idk. I used VSCode on Win10 and now i'm using sublime on Linux . Not used Mac till now

Comment: Its fine :) No Problem.  Some other amazing programmer helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi just found a solution here!
Initially guess it should be a problem with zsh.
so first open your terminal and type

> open ~/.zshrc

at this point you will see text editor pops up with a zsh config file.

Add

> export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home

to the last line in that file, and save the file quit.

Then just reopen the VSC and you will notice everything would back to normal as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. When running the same Java program, it worked in terminal but VS Code couldn't detect java.

All it turned out to be was I forgot to add Code itself to Path after reinstallation, nothing to do with Java.